# Creating private cocoapods and use CommonCrypto

Tags: ios, cocoapods

Currently, I am moving some of my codes to cocoapods so that our team can share. In one of my code,

I need to import like this. It is in CryptoProxy.h and CryptoProxy.m.

```
#import <CommonCrypto/CommonDigest.h>
#import <CommonCrypto/CommonHMAC.h>
#import <CommonCrypto/CommonCryptor.h>
```

I can still build and run locally. I can also lint lib.

> pod lib lint WWAutoupdate.podspec --verbose

Problem is that when I lint spec,

> pod spec lint WWAutoupdate.podspec --verbose

I got many errors like this. How shall I solve that? Do I need to import some kind of library?

> ```
> - ERROR | [iOS] xcodebuild:  WWAutoupdate/WWAutoupdate/Classes/Library/Hawk/CryptoProxy.m:81:62:
> ```
>
> error: use of undeclared identifier 'CC_LONG'
>       - ERROR | [iOS] xcodebuild:  WWAutoupdate/WWAutoupdate/Classes/Library/Hawk/CryptoProxy.m:81:12:
>   error: use of undeclared identifier 'kCCHmacAlgSHA1'
>       - ERROR | [iOS] xcodebuild:  WWAutoupdate/WWAutoupdate/Classes/Library/Hawk/CryptoProxy.m:91:24:
>   error: use of undeclared identifier 'CC_SHA224_DIGEST_LENGTH'
>       - ERROR | [iOS] xcodebuild:  WWAutoupdate/WWAutoupdate/Classes/Library/Hawk/CryptoProxy.m:93:64:
>   error: use of undeclared identifier 'CC_LONG'
>       - ERROR | [iOS] xcodebuild:  WWAutoupdate/WWAutoupdate/Classes/Library/Hawk/CryptoProxy.m:93:12:
>   error: use of undeclared identifier 'kCCHmacAlgSHA224'
>       - ERROR | [iOS] xcodebuild:  WWAutoupdate/WWAutoupdate/Classes/Library/Hawk/CryptoProxy.m:103:24:
>   error: use of undeclared identifier 'CC_SHA256_DIGEST_LENGTH'
>       - ERROR | [iOS] xcodebuild:  WWAutoupdate/WWAutoupdate/Classes/Library/Hawk/CryptoProxy.m:105:64:
>   error: use of undeclared identifier 'CC_LONG'
>       - ERROR | [iOS] xcodebuild:  WWAutoupdate/WWAutoupdate/Classes/Library/Hawk/CryptoProxy.m:105:12:
>   error:

Answer (score 0):

Change all `#import <CommonCrypto/*.h>` to `#import <CommonCrypto/CommonCrypto.h>`.